# update childByAutoId with updateChildValues

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a child node in my firebase database by using childByAutoID and updateChildAt(). When I execute the code the type is updated, however it is outside of the node as seen below.

[image]

the type: 3 should be updated inside of the node that says type: 2

the code that I am using to execute this looks like

```
let DB_REF = Database.database().reference()
let WORK_PROG_REF = DB_REF.child("workInProgress")


    func completeJobProgress() {
    let workUser = self.workerUser
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let workerId = workUser?.uid
    let address = workerUser?.address
    let createDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        let user = User(dictionary: dictionary as [String : AnyObject])
        workUser?.uid = snapshot.key

        let docData: [String: Any] = ["workerId": uid!,
                                      "creationDate": createDate,
                                      "fromId" : workerId!,
                                      "location": address!,
                                      "type": 3,
                                      "checked": 0,]


        self.setJobToCompletedInDatabase(uid: uid!, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
        self.postJobNotificationsIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: workerId!, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])


//how I initially got the type: 3 to save under the node was by using the line below 

WORK_PROG_REF.child(uid!).child("type").setValue(3)


        print(workerId!)

     }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
        })

        print("Finished saving user info")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            print("Dismissal complete")
        })


    }
```

this just sets the type to be under the node. I tried using the code below but with the line below, I am getting the error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable: Any]'

```
     WORK_PROG_REF.child(uid!).updateChildValues("type").setValue(3)
```

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Solution With Transaction:

```
WORK_PROG_REF.child(uid!).child("-M1bOYAcP_IMFbgz8siD").runTransactionBlock({ (result: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            if var objInfo = result.value as? [String: Any] {
                objInfo["type"] = 3

                // Set value and report transaction success
                result.value = objInfo

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: result)
            }else{
                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: result)
            }
        }) { (error,completion,snap) in
            //Handle Error
        }
```

Solution without transaction:

```
WORK_PROG_REF.child(uid!).child("-M1bOYAcP_IMFbgz8siD"). child("type").setValue(3)
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I am getting error Value of type 'DatabaseQuery' has no member 'runTransactionBlock'

Comment: I have updated my answer, do you have id: -M1bOYAcP_IMFbgz8siD somewhere in your code? if yes the above solution will work.

Comment: sorry for delayed response but it did not work. I do not have the -M1bOYAcP_IMFbgz8siD id in my code

Comment: when you get that data you get this value as a key, right now you must be using only values.

Comment: Your code ended up working perfectly. but why is -M1bOYAcP_IMFbgz8siD needed to run this? If there is a different autoId will this still work?

Comment: You can Store this id in your bean and use later for this purpose